# I would like to create docs for a shelf button in Maya when the mouse hovers over the button

Tags: python, maya

I have a custom shelf in Maya with buttons built using the 'shelfButton' command. I would like to include short descriptions of what the button does when the mouse cursor hovers over the button. I have tried a couple of the available flags, like 'annotation,' but so far I have not gotten anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shelfButton` command inside Maya has no flag for the desired behavior. Any string passed with the `annotation` flag will be displayed on Maya's native help box (At the buttom of the Maya UI). If you really want the behavior you may have to look into Qt.